# how do i get opening and closing balance for each productCode

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

how do i get opening and closing balance for each productCode using the screenshot table.
sql server 2008.

From the shot, the product code 1 has been issued twice and the last balance reflects the current balance....i need to get the last balance for all product codes.

```
  select TOP 1 Balance as OpeningBalance 
  from StockTransfer where ProductCode = 1 and TransferType = 'Product' 
  and TransactionDate between '2013-03-17' and '2013-03-22' 

  select TOP 1 Balance as ClosingBalance 
  from StockTransfer where ProductCode = 1 and TransferType = 'Product' 
  and TransactionDate between '2013-03-17' and '2013-03-22' 
  order by TransactionDate desc
```

but this only works for one product.

Comment: just to confirm - each product can have a different transaction date?

Comment: This screen shot is helpful, but you also need to add to the question with words/code, nobody can copy and paste code out of your image. Nobody can copy and paste your sample data to test any solutions. Please help us to help you and add text to your question. Also, what version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: @Nitesh i have tried: select TOP 1 Balance as OpeningBalance from StockTransfer where ProductCode = 1 and TransferType = 'Product' and TransactionDate 
between   '2013-03-17' and '2013-03-22'     

select TOP 1 Balance as ClosingBalance from StockTransfer where ProductCode = 1 and TransferType = 'Product' and TransactionDate 
between   '2013-03-17' and '2013-03-22'
order by TransactionDate desc  ....... but this only works for one product.

Comment: @Juliusz yes they do have

Comment: did u tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
  (select TOP 1 Balance as OpeningBalance 
   from StockTransfer 
   where ProductCode = ST.ProductCode and TransferType = 'Product' 
   and TransactionDate between '2013-03-17' and '2013-03-22' 
  ) As opening balance,

  (select TOP 1 Balance as ClosingBalance 
   from StockTransfer 
   where ProductCode = ST.ProductCode and TransferType = 'Product' 
   and TransactionDate between '2013-03-17' and '2013-03-22' 
   order by TransactionDate desc
   ) as colosing balance

FROM 
 StockTransfer  ST 
WHERE  TransactionDate between '2013-03-17' and '2013-03-22' 

GROUP BY ProductCode
```

this will returns the same result for entire products

Comment: multiple uncorrelated results

Comment: @MarkBannister Yes. I forgot the `group by` . Updated the answer. thanku

Comment: @Nitesh just re-testing to make sure it returns the appropriate data.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select s.*,
        row_number() over (partition by ProductCode 
                           order by TransactionDate) ra,
        row_number() over (partition by ProductCode 
                           order by TransactionDate desc) rd
 from StockTransfer
 where TransferType = 'Product' and 
       TransactionDate between '2013-03-17' and '2013-03-22')
select ProductCode,
       max(case ra when 1 then Balance end) OpeningBalance,
       max(case rd when 1 then Balance end) ClosingBalance
from cte
group by ProductCode
```

Comment: @froodo: That's because I misread `TransferType` as `TransactionType` - I have now corrected it; try now.

Comment: guess the issue has to do with the TransactionDate...the query picks the Most recent Balance as Opening Balance in a situation where  there is a more than one data available on same date.

Comment: @froodo: If there is a time component to the TransactionDate, it will pick the **earliest** Balance as the Opening Balance, not the most recent. If there is no time component to the TransactionDate, how can you tell which is the most recent?

Answer (score 0):

As per comments above - it is nice to provide your queries in the text format, so one does not have to retype it.

Now, to solve your problem, you need to use correlated subquery. I believe all SQL database engines support them. Please refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) - it is a good starting point.